# How to use openstack on client side

Tags: javascript, openstack, object-storage

I try to make a upload/download services of files for my website, and i'm trying to use the object storage from openstack. The thing is, i have no problem doing it via php and openstack php sdk, but when i'm trying to do it via some javascript, i can't find a good sdk or methods.
I'm not using node, I have a php server, and a javascript client. I would like to uploads or download files directly from the javascript client. I don't want the file to transfer through the php server. I managed to create openstack tokens with the php sdk, maybe i could send those to the javascript so then they can authenticate? It's been one week of searching with no solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openstack has a S3 plugin that can ease your search for a library/sdk.

Otherwise, you should forge a temporary URL server-side, I'm sure your PHP library has tooling for this. The URL can then be used client-side to PUT the file.

The temporary URL is forged in a way to open temporary write-only access for the upload. There is also the same kind of URL to open read-only access to some elements.

So, either the client requests for a place to upload to the PHP which sends back the URL, or simply have the client upload the file to your PHP that will forge the link and then redirect the request to the URL.

Comment: I found a solution. I used the php lib to generate an openstack token with which i then forge a html put query and it worked perfectly. I didn't know about the S3 plugin, i'll look into that too, thanks!